# How do you assign slots to .wav files in r

Tags: r, wav, slots

Hoping this will be a palm to the forehead for missing something.
Using R Consol and I'm trying to analyze .wav files. I've loaded seewave, tuneR, soundecology, warbleR, and many supporting packages. And this is the message I get;

> bioacoustics::read_wav("A1.wav", time_exp=1, from=NULL, to=NULL)

Wave Object
    Number of Samples:      1584000
    Duration (seconds):     33
    Samplingrate (Hertz):   48000
    Channels (Mono/Stereo): Mono
    PCM (integer format):   TRUE
    Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    24

> fspec("A1.wav",channel=left,FFT_size=256,FFT_overlap=0.875, FFT_win="hann",LPF,HPF=0,tlim=NULL,flim=NULL, rotate=FALSE,to_dB=TRUE)
>   Error in slot(wave, "samp.rate") : 
>     cannot get a slot ("samp.rate") from an object of type "character"
>   How/where do I assign the slots with this .wav information. 
>   Thanks for helping,
>   Laurel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the code in your question correctly, you should probably do:

```
myWave <- bioacoustics::read_wav("A1.wav", time_exp=1, from=NULL, to=NULL)

bioacoustics::fspec(myWave, channel=left, FFT_size=256, FFT_overlap=0.875,
                    FFT_win="hann", LPF, HPF=0, tlim=NULL, flim=NULL,
                    rotate=FALSE, to_dB=TRUE)
```

The error message indicates that you have passed an object of type character (i.e. `"A1.wav"`) to the `fspec` function, which instead expects a `Wave` object, as created by `bioacoustics::read_wav`. The `Wave` object contains a slot called `"samp.rate"`, so then everything should be fine.

Comment: I still seem to be having an issue getting the slots right. Using the code, here's the error msg;   bioacoustics::fspec(myWave, channel=left, FFT_size=256, FFT_overlap=0.875,
+                     FFT_win="hann", LPF, HPF=0, tlim=NULL, flim=NULL,
+                     rotate=FALSE, to_dB=TRUE)
Error in slot(wave, channel) : object 'left' not found

Comment: I tried the ACI in seewave and it works. I'll keep at bioacoustics to see what it wants. Thanks for the help.